# Creating a project from sandbox using vscode

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, sfdx-plugin

We donot have sfdx enabled in our instances. Can I use vscode IDE and create a proejct from sandbox with any of the salesforce extensions.

I see the documentation around creating a scratch org, then retrieving and deploying the components using sfdx command. But is there a way to create a project without devhub enabled in envrionemnts. I belive I would not be able to use sfdx with my sandbox environmets with out devhub enable.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevHub is not a requirement for sfdx. You can use "Create New Project" or "Create New Project From Manifest", then authorize against your production/development/sandbox orgs. If you wanted to do this with terminal commands, it would look like this:

```
sfdx force:project:create -n desired-project-name
cd desired-project-name
sfdx force:auth:web:login -a desired-alias -r https://someinstance.salesforce.com -s
```

You'll want to [read the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_any_org.htm) for more details, but in summary, you can use the "Retrieve from Org" and "Deploy to Org" commands to deploy to most orgs. You'll need to convert to the metadata API format for deployment to production, however (`force:source:convert`), or create change sets/packages to manage your metadata.

In the future, it will likely be possible to use "Deploy to Org" to directly deploy to production without the conversion step.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. It takes some time to get used to commands to retrive, convert and deploy back to salesforce. I guess I would be missing ctrl+s shortcut which used to save the changes back to salesforce from other editors. The advantage I see is that I donot have to pay for plugins and IDEs.

Comment: @Venkata The [mo-dx-plugin](https://github.com/msrivastav13/mo-dx-plugin) can help with the Ctrl-S feature if you're interested in adding it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vscode extensions for salesforce without need to enable Dev Hub or scratch org .

There is a solid [documentation](https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/user-guide/org-development-model) on this .

Here are few things you would need to consider if you are moving away from the mavensmate or eclipse

1. There is need for you to create package.xml and you will retrieve metadata using that .
2. You will see the source format is in [DX source format](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_source_file_format.htm) than the traditional metadata format . DX Source format has additional breakdown of object metadata making it easier to manage object metadata .

Comment: Thanks Mohith. The documentation links helped. I was under the wrong impression that SFDX and CLI works only if devhub is enabled. Yes, I did notice the break down of the components in objects.